# Update between 3 tables Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql, sql-update

i got one question.

I got 3 tables as `Table1`, `Table2`, `Table3`.

1. `Table1` --> Column 1 (`PLATE`), Column 2 (`DATE`)
2. `Table2` --> Column 1 (`PLATE`), Column 2 (`BRAND`)
3. `Table3` --> Column 1 (`BRAND`), Column 2 (`DATE`)

I want to fill the `DATE` column of `Table1` with the information in the `DATE` column of `Table3`

We can join `Table1 (PLATE)` and `Table2 (PLATE)`, `Table2(BRAND)` and `Table3 (BRAND)`

I tried that but gave an error (cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table)

```
UPDATE
    (
        SELECT TABLE1.DATE AS OLD_DATE,
               TABLE3.DATE AS NEW_DATE
          FROM TABLE1 
          JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.PLATE = TABLE2.PLATE
          JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE3.BRAND=TABLE2.BRAND
    ) TABLES
SET TABLES.OLD_DATE = TABLES.NEW_DATE
  ;
```

How can i do this update?

Thanks for helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **`MERGE`** with **`MATCHED`** option would be a good choice for your case such as

```sql
MERGE INTO table1 t1 
USING (SELECT t3."date", t2.plate
         FROM table1 t1
         JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.plate = t2.plate
         JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.brand = t2.brand) tt
          ON ( t1.plate = tt.plate )
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1."date" = tt."date"
```

***`date`** is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as a column name unless double-quoted. So, that's quoted. Btw, quoted identifiers are case-sensitive, I prefered **"date"** (not **"DATE"**) to be the column of the table*

Answer (score 1):

This error message indicates that a Plate might map to different Brands or Brands might map to different Dates. Therefore the inline view is not updateable because it's not a [key preserved table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/views.htm#ADMIN11782).

Try to set the value one-by-one:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 t1
   SET t1.OLD_DATE =
       (SELECT MIN(t3.DATE) AS NEW_DATE
          FROM TABLE2 t2
          JOIN TABLE3 t3 ON t2.BRAND = t3.BRAND
         WHERE t2.PLATE = t1.PLATE)
 WHERE EXISTS((SELECT t3.DATE AS NEW_DATE
                FROM TABLE2 t2
                JOIN TABLE3 t3 ON t2.BRAND = t3.BRAND
               WHERE t2.PLATE = t1.PLATE))
```

Comment: Thansk for your answer :) I've added the answer below. can you check please